# Using while loop to find smallest user input number

Tags: python, input, while-loop

Hey guys I cannot figure out how to use a while loop to find the smallest number entered by a user. I know I have to assign a number entered to stop the program then print the smallest number that was entered. This is what I have so far:

```
while(True):
    A = int(input("Enter a Number (Use -1 to Stop): " ))
    if(A == -1):
        break
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily store all the values in a list and then use `min`, but if you insist not to:

```
min_val = None
while True:
    A = int(input("Enter a Number (Use -1 to Stop): " ))
    if A == -1:
        break
    if not min_val or A < min_val:  
        min_val = A
```

The `if` checks whether it is the first value the user inputs or if the new value is smaller than the previous minimum.
When the `while` breaks, `min_val` will either be `None` (if the first value the user inputs is `-1`) or the minimum value the user entered.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the number before the loop, then update its value if the new number is less. This should do:

```
# initialize minimum
minimum = int(input("Enter a Number: " ))
while(True):
    A = int(input("Enter a Number (Use -1 to Stop): " ))
    if(A == -1):
        break
    if minimum > A:
        minimum = A
print(minimum)
```

Comment: this worked, thank you so much! How did you know to initialize it?

Comment: If you're going to compare with new values, you should at least have an initial value :-)

Answer (score 1):

Code below would suit your need:

```
b = -1
while(True):
    A = int(input("Enter a Number (Use -1 to Stop): " ))
    if(A == -1):
        print b
        break
    b = b if A > b else A
```

**Good Luck !**